# How to apply border to html select button?

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

[image]

As shown in the picture I applied a border radius for the select tag but when pressing on it the arrow button isn't taking the border radius.
(Only in Opera browser)
css:

```
.App select{
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: #dc3545 solid 1px;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have any CSS which you have written to share with us?

Comment: Does `overflow: hidden`  the trick?

Comment: Does outline: 0 help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: which browser is that because it works fine in chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/3x17cs6y/

Comment: @Pete this is on opera

Comment: @LinkinTED nope overflow didn't work

Comment: @TobyLoby no it didn't work

Comment: Are you really bothered about a browser that hardly anyone uses?  More people use samsung browser and I bet you haven't tested that one

Comment: @KayAngevare I edited the question and added the css

Answer (score 0):

The outline shown is most likely the `:focus` state. I would keep this on for accessibility reasons; some people physically cannot use a mouse, or simply prefer to navigate a page via the keyboard.

Knowing this, you can toggle the focus state with CSS:

```
:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried it now, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is simple, just give in:

```
.App select:focus {
    overflow: inline;
    outline: none;
```

Comment: I tried it now, it didn't work

Comment: Ok. Try "overflow: hidden". If it doesn't work, Tag me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).